# How to Use Sprites in InstancedMesh with Three.js and React Three Fiber in React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, sprite

I'm currently working on a NextJS proyect with React Three Fiber where I've created a Galaxy component that generates a starry background using instanced spheres. However, I'm trying to replace these spheres with sprites to improve performance and add a different visual style. Unfortunately, I've run into some issues during this conversion process.

When I attempt to replace the spheres with sprites in my Galaxy component, I encounter unexpected behavior and my scene doesn't render.

**What I'm Trying to Achieve:**

I want to modify the Galaxy component to use sprites instead of spheres while maintaining the instanced rendering approach. I've updated the code to use SpriteMaterial and BufferGeometry, but the results are not what I expected. The sprites are not being displayed, and the scene doesn't render.

**Code:**

```
function Galaxy(props:GalaxyProps){
  const meshRef = useRef<THREE.InstancedMesh>(null)
  const starsPos = useMemo<THREE.Vector3[]>(()=>{
    return generatePositions(props.count)
  }, [props.count])

  const starObject = useMemo(()=>new THREE.Object3D(), [])
  const material = useMemo(()=>new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"#ffff7f"}), [])
  const geometry = useMemo(()=>new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 10, 5), [])

  useEffect(()=>{
    for (let i =0; i < starsPos.length; i++){
      starObject.position.copy(starsPos[i])
      starObject.updateMatrix()
      meshRef.current!.setMatrixAt(i, starObject.matrix)
    }
    meshRef.current!.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true
  },[starObject, starsPos])
  
  return <instancedMesh ref={meshRef} args={[geometry, material, starsPos.length]}
  ></instancedMesh>
}
```

**Modified Code:**

```
function Galaxy(props:GalaxyProps){
  const meshRef = useRef<THREE.InstancedMesh>(null)
  const starsPos = useMemo<THREE.Vector3[]>(()=>{
    return generatePositions(props.count)
  }, [props.count])

  const starObject = useMemo(()=>new THREE.Sprite(), [])
  const texture = useTexture('/images/star.png')
  const material = useMemo(()=>new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture, color:'ffff7f'}), [texture])

  useEffect(()=>{
    for (let i =0; i < starsPos.length; i++){
      starObject.position.copy(starsPos[i])
      starObject.updateMatrix()
      meshRef.current!.setMatrixAt(i, starObject.matrix)
    }
    meshRef.current!.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true
  },[starObject, starsPos])
  
  return <instancedMesh ref={meshRef} args={[starObject.geometry, material, starsPos.length]}
  ></instancedMesh>
}
```